# How to fetch Multiple column value from database to cursor object

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my sqlite class file

```
public class MySqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "student_info";

    public MySqlite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlite) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String query = "CREATE TABLE student_datatable(first_name Text, last_name Text, gender Text, street Text, city Text, contact Text)";
        sqlite.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlite, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqlite.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student_datatable");
        onCreate(sqlite);
    }

    public void addrecord(String firstname, String lastname, String radiovalue,
            String street, String city, String contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqlite = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("first_name", firstname);
        cv.put("last_name", lastname);
        cv.put("gender", radiovalue);
        cv.put("street", street);
        cv.put("city", city);
        cv.put("contact", contact);

        sqlite.insert("student_datatable", null, cv);
        sqlite.close();
    }

    public String searchrecord(String firstname) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String lastnamefromtable = null;
        String param[] = new String[1];
        param[0] = firstname;
        Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(
                "Select * from student_datatable where first_name=?", param);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                lastnamefromtable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name"));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return lastnamefromtable;
    }

    public void deleterecord(String firstname) {
        String Table_name = "student_info";
        String column_name = "first_name";
        SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String lastnamefromtable = null;
        String param[] = new String[1];
        param[0] = firstname;
        sql.execSQL("DELETE FROM student_info where first_name=?", param);
    }

}
```

here i am fetching only lastname according to firstname, but i want to fetch other value also like gender,street,city & contact from database to cursor and from cursor to my following activity

```
public class Searchrecord extends Activity {

    EditText firstname;
    TextView getlastname;
    MySqlite mysql;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchrecord);
        firstname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        getlastname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mysql=new MySqlite(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void search(View v)
    {
        if(firstname.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Provide value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String value=mysql.searchrecord(firstname.getText().toString());
            getlastname.setText(value);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: in the same way as you did retrieved the last name, your query returns all columns and your code only reads 1.

Answer (score 1):

please try follwing code

```
        public ArrayList<String> searchrecord(String firstname) 
     {
     ArrayList<String> allitems=new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String lastnamefromtable = null;
   String param[] = new String[1];
   param[0] = firstname;
   Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(
        "Select * from student_datatable where first_name=?", param);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        lastnamefromtable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name"));
      allitems.add(lastnamefromtable )

    } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
  return allitems;
 }
```

inMain activity

```
ArrayList<String> allitems=db.searchrecord(String firstname);
iterate for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your methods like below,

```
public Bundle searchrecord(String firstname) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Bundle cursorData = new Bundle();
    String param[] = new String[1];
    param[0] = firstname;
    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(
            "Select * from student_datatable where first_name=?", param);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            bundle.putString("last_name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name"));
            bundle.putString("gender", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gender"));  
            bundle.putString("street", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("street"));  
            bundle.putString("city", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("city"));  
            bundle.putString("contact", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("contact"));  

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return cursorData;
}

public void search(View v)
{
    if(firstname.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Provide value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Bundle bundle=mysql.searchrecord(firstname.getText().toString());
        getlastname.setText(bundle.get("last_name"));
        String gender=bundle.get("gender");
        String contact=bundle.get("contact");
        String street=bundle.get("street");
        String city=bundle.get("city");

    }

}
```